# Why .net shows version conflict for same nuget package which is internal dependency for 3rd party library/package?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, nuget-package

Conflicting versions of Newtonsoft.json library.

Steps to Reproduce issue:

1. Create 2 .net c# project
2. Project 1 include IdentityModel with some method
3. Project 2 include Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost with some method
4. Pack them and create nuget package and publish it locally (2 package will get created)
5. Now create a test project and install both nuget package in it.
6. Call the method from those installed packages. You will get conflict error regarding Newtonsoft.json

I have two custom plugin developed on top of Kafka and REST. To fullfill the plugin I am using 3rd party libraries as part of dependency. Dependency internally uses Newtonsoft.Json package with their specific version.

package use for developing kafka plugin
[image: package use for developing kafka plugin]

package use for developing REST plugin
[image: package use for developing REST plugin]

.net should not show the error

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been
>   thrown by the target of an invocation.   ---->
>   System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

as 3rd party library should refer their package according to their version. For me if I navigate to

> %USERPROFILE%.nuget\packages

location I can see version graph [image: versions] for newtonsoft.json and 3rd party lib should use them at runtime. Version 6.0.4 and 11.0.2 should load at it's runtime.

Comment: you might need to adjust your web.config, since its looking for 6.0.0.0 and not 6.0.4, maybe check if there is something there that is not quite right

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen you are right. I was thinking in terms of plugin developer. Suppose if I deliver both the plugin to my end user then I worried if they get conflict. Can we handle version at my plugin level itself?

Comment: I found a resource that might help you. But I have not done this my self. Maybe some information can help you here: https://michaelscodingspot.com/how-to-resolve-net-reference-and-nuget-package-version-conflicts/

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen I used AssemblyResolve event, which fires when an assembly’s failed to load (from solution 2). It's working for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please use **Update-Package** command to update all the packages in all projects

Comment: If I run Update-Package command IdentityModel (3.10.5) and Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost (5.2.7) uses Newtonsoft.Json internally. This command will  not upgrade their Newtonsoft.Json used package. I don't have Newtonsoft.Json  in my project. It's part of dependency for 3rd packages.

Comment: what if you used reinstall option for the update-package to reinstall all the packages instead of updating them ?

Comment: i have another idea , is to installl Newjsonsoft.dll version 6.0.0.0 using gacutil ,if this is the case so (the need to use the same dlls but with diffrent versions ) , i think gacutil will help

Comment: If I run Update-Package with reinstall then I get error because it's not in my project: 'Newtonsoft.Json' was not installed in any project. Update fai
led. My concern is IdentityModel (3.10.5) Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost (5.2.7) uses Newtonsoft.Json which I can't control. They are downloading the Newtonsoft.Json according to their need but why still conflicting.

Comment: could you please use gacutil to register newjsonsoft.dll version 6 ?